# The "grey market" of loans

Tags: phrase-request

In Hebrew, the term "grey market" refers to a market of loans given by private lenders, with the following characteristics:

- Usury rates are much higher: even 1% *per day* is common.
- Collection is much stricter: a defaulting debtor is subject to mental and physical violence and may even be murdered.
- Lenders are usually related to and cooperate with underworld criminal organizations.

The term has a very strong negative connotation. Most people strongly hate or fear the "grey market" of loans.

In contrast, the term "grey market" in English refers to something entirely different - a legal but unofficial market of products. It doesn't have such a strong negative connotation.

What English term best describes the "grey market" of loans which I described above?

Comment: Though it's not as extreme as what you've described, we have what is called [*predatory lending*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predatory_lending).

Comment: BTW, in English, "usury" means "excessively high interest rates". That said, in the US we're content to regard interest rates exceeding 20% as not usurious.

Comment: For reference, [***Grey Market***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_market)

Comment: Are such collection terms as you mention legal? If not, it should be more like [***Black Market***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_market) in English.

Comment: @user3169 physical violence is illegal, but there are other, 'barely legal' types of violence. For example: the lender gives the debtor a very tough handshake with a very tough gaze that says it all; the lender sends several very big guys that surround the debtor on the street and tell him: "you must pay" in a frightening voice. The lender threatens to call the debtor's ill parents and tell them that their son is in debts, etc... it's a "grey zone".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In AmE, this type of lender is a "Loan Shark," and the practice is thus some times called "loan sharking."